# query_posts making conditional statement disapear in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I have a very peculiar issue with wordpress at the moment. I am new to WordPress and it is perhaps why I am finding it a bit of a mess in terms of code structure but I appreciate the amount of information we can find online on the platform.

After search through several forums, I finally found a piece of code which loads posts based on specific categories on the homepage:

Statement #1

```
<?php if(is_home()) {
query_posts('cat=6,9&&showposts=7');
}
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
endwhile; ?>
```

This works as it should but there is one very odd thing happening. In my sidebar.php template I have a conditional code for the homepage which displays a canvas with some content. I want this to only show in the homepage therefore this is how I am doing it:

Statement #2

```
<?php if(is_home()):?>
<div id="portrait_image">
<div class="container">
<canvas id="panel" width="370" height="175"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

This also works fine EXCEPT that when I added the first `if(is_home)` statement above, it seems to disable the second `if(is_home)` statement for some reason. I scratched my head for hours on the issue, also noting that if I place the second statement above the first one it suddenly works.

But then I discovered something even weirder. If I remove `cat=6,9&&` from statement #1, then #2 works. I see no logic as to how calling different posts categories would have in obstructing a conditional statement which simply calls a canvas if you are in the homepage inside the sidebar.php template.

Has anyone come across this weird issue, is my syntax wrong or could point me in the direction to resolving it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: P.S. By the way I have tried adding even just "hello" to the second statement to see if it would work but still nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem with my sidebar.php .

Call `wp_reset_query` function before second `if(is_home)`

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

From Codex WordPress:

> wp_reset_query() restores the $wp_query and global post data to the
>   original main query.

I also found [this blog post](http://webstractions.com/wordpress/undocumented-wordpress-query-function-wp_reset_query/) which describes in detail this function.

It seems the author also had similar problem as you.

Comment: You are a star! It fixed my problem! But what a dirty fix hey? Do you know the reason why that happens?

Comment: wp_reset_query() restores the $wp_query and global post data to the original main query. Look at the above link to learn more.

Comment: If you found this answer useful, please take a moment to accept it by clicking on the big checkbox on the left side of this answer.